# db:migrate modifies enum types in schema.rb provoking failure running db:schema:load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, enums

**Stack**

Ruby 3.0.0,
Rails 6.1.3,
Postgres 14,
macOS 12.2.1

**Problem**

When running `db:migrate` in my project, any enum in `schema.rb` go

- from: `t.enum "XXX", default: '{}', null: false, array: true, enum_name: "XXX"`
- to:   `t.enum "XXX", default: [], null: false, array: true, enum_name: "XXX"`

**What's the impact?**

When running `db:schema:load` afterwards, it fails with this error: `TypeError: can't quote Array`. `db:schema:load` works just fine when the enum contains `'{}'` as default value.

**Question**

Is someone aware of this error? What should I do?

Thank you very much for helping !

Comment: which database (and version) are you using?

Comment: My bad, just edited my question.

Comment: @Jad Postgres 14 !

Comment: You're running into the limits of the Ruby SQL schema dumper - which basically just handles the bare fundamentals and doesn't deal well with database specific features like the extended types provided by Postgres. The solution is to switch to SQL schema dumps instead. https://blog.appsignal.com/2020/01/15/the-pros-and-cons-of-using-structure-sql-in-your-ruby-on-rails-application.html

Comment: Thanks @max, I'll give this a try !